# How return the length value of the largest array through method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, intellij-idea, methods

### Code fragments are in one separate Class.

There are two arrays. Size of first is 5, second is 8.

```
double[] x = new double[5];
double[] y = new double[8];
```

I need to write a method that will compare the length of two arrays (**x, y**) and return the length of the largest array (**y**).

I tried it, but **IntelliJ IDEA** shows a syntax error.

```
// version 1
private int getLargeArray( double[] x, double[] y ) {

    boolean checkLargeArray = x.length < y.length;
    int result;

    if( checkLargeArray == true ) {
        result = y.length; // 'result' is ignored
    } else if( checkLargeArray == false ) {
        result = x.length; // 'result' is ignored
    }

    return result; // uninitialized variable
}
```

**Java** does not see the variable **' result '**, which is in **' if '**, so it does not return it. If i write **0** for variable **' result '** in method start, it return **0** and ignored the **' if '** block.

The second version also does not work.
*As I know, Java does not support a return, which is in blocks if, else and for.*

```
// version 2
private int getLargeArray( double[] x, double[] y ) {

    boolean checkLargeArray = x.length < y.length;

    if( checkLargeArray == true ) {
        return y.length;
    } else if( checkLargeArray == false ) {
        return x.length;
    }
} // waiting for return...
```

---

**IntelliJ IDEA** screenshots.

[Syntax error of version 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDRnw.png)

[Syntax error of version 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Retim.png)

Comment: If you simplify your logic (use the boolean as the condition and use the else without another if block) it should work

Comment: `return Math.max(x.length, y.length);` **EDIT**: if this is an assignment and you can't use Math.max then use Russiancold's method below.

Comment: *As I know, Java does not support a return, which is in blocks if, else and for.* - this is not true, it will return on an `if statement` if you have at least an `else` on the end of your statement like a `default` in switch. your statement has `else if` on the last that's why it may occur a `dead code` on the last execution of your method.

Comment: At version 1: you must initialize your variable result: `int result = 0`
At version 2: you must have an `else` block or change `else if( checkLargeArray == false ) {}` to `else {}`

Answer (score 1):

You must intialize your variable result at the start, because with your code the variable result may not get initialized. Like: 
    `int result = 0;`
with that your first codeblock should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
if(x.length < y.length) {
    return y.length;
}
else {
   return x.length;
}
```

To make your code work just do what IDE asks for. In the first case try to initialize result as 0. In the second case add `return` statement. Idea asks for it because in some cases both of conditional statements might be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getLargeArray( double[] x, double[] y ) {
    return x.length > y.length ? x.length : y.length;
}
```

This is the simplest thing you can do